# Odd strikethrough behavior in Suggested Edits

Tags: bug, review-queues, design, suggested-edits

On [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34218378) I noticed some odd behavior in the strikeout:

[image]

I observed this on iPadOS 16.2's stock Safari and no userscripts. I'm not entirely sure what's wrong, but this extension of the strikethrough beyond the text seems to only happen in monospace text, not regular text.

Comment: Looks like this is somehow the div that should just be plain text that gets the strikethrough applied and creates this. If I inspect the element and edit the div out, it fixes the odd behaviour

Comment: And so, I can reproduce this on Safari version 16.3 (18614.4.6.1.6) on a Mac.

Comment: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FK63.png) sheds some light on what's going on there. The problem with inline code blocks having trouble wrapping is well-known by now: there is a huge number of whitespaces on that line.

Comment: Source link: [`https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/87b93c67-55d3-4095-8bbf-6642c1337395/view-source`](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/87b93c67-55d3-4095-8bbf-6642c1337395/view-source). 128 spaces between *"::before"* and *"Your payment could not be taken"* (at least when copied from that page; it is not always representative of the real source, in particular newlines). No trailing space.

Comment: (Source link: First constructed timeline URL: [`https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76011602/timeline`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76011602/timeline) (or click through to it on [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76011602/)). Then the GUID (87b93c67-55d3-4095-8bbf-6642c1337395) from the first (at the bottom) timestamp's URL, 2023-04-14 04:29:18Z: `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76011602/timeline#history_87b93c67-55d3-4095-8bbf-6642c1337395`. There may be an easier way.)